# How do you get F2-F12 Function Key input sent to a running terminal application inside Visual Studio 2019 integrated Terminal (Developer PowerShell)?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I've been using the built-in Terminal in Visual Studio 2019. It works great--except for the (console) application that I run from within this integrated (PowerShell) is not receiving any Function Key presses.  E.g., F3-F12 function keys on my keyboard all mean something to this console application I am running, but pressing function keys gets intercepted by the Visual Studio 2019 IDE, rather than "falling through" to the application running inside the integrated Terminal window/tab of the VS2019 IDE.  In Visual Studio 2019, (**NOT Visual Studio Code**!) when I press the F3 function key, it moves the focus away from the Terminal tab where the console app is running, into a nearby source window (an open C++ header file) and proceeds to execute a search for whatever the last string used by the "Find" dialog was. How can I change that behavior, so that if the Terminal tab/window has the focus, then the F3 will go to that Terminal's running windows console application, and not get intercepted and turn into a Search? It seems like this should be possible, however, I'm not finding any help with Google/Stackoverflow--most of my clever attempts to NOT find "Visual Studio Code" information fail, and land in online "Visual Studio Code" help pages. :-(  Does anyone have a solution that works for Visual Studio 2019 IDE? Once again please do NOT assume I am asking about "Visual Studio Code" because if you simply search for this question online, you WILL get redirected to "Visual Studio Code" not "Visual Studio 2019 Professional". I am asking about "Visual Studio 2019 IDE" and NOT NOT NOT about how to accomplish this using "Visual Studio Code" - a COMPLETELY different IDE that I am not using. My team does NOT use the "Visual Studio Code" product.

Comment: Did you try running the program outside of the IDE, i.e. the generated `.exe` file, directly?

Comment: I can run the program fine outside the IDE, yes.  Get the F-keys and all works fine.  The problem is that I have to repeat extra steps to do that outside the IDE - which involves using a Telnet server (Pragma) with a telnet client (PuTTY) in order to properly render Unicode characters (such as multibyte CJK characters) because the Cmd.exe console cannot render them.  However, PowerShell renders *all* of this application's Unicode characters no problem. So... outside IDE, is a PITA.  Inside IDE--via developer PowerShell is GREAT--if the Function keys would work!

Comment: Just FYI, running this application outside of the IDE is not an acceptable solution.  I'm specifically looking for a way to get the Terminal window (only when it has the focus!) to allow all function key presses to "pass through" to the application that is running there, instead of intercepting those keystrokes and interpreting F3 (for example) as a "Find" command for Visual Studio IDE.